# Why can't I build VSTO projects anymore on my build servers?

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, azure-pipelines, vsto

Since updating Visual Studio Build Tools on our build servers to 17.2 (we had 17.1.6 before), we can't build VSTO projects anymore.

We get the following error:

```
"D:\6\s\vsto-test.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\6\s\src\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\6\s\src\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1.csproj]
```

I still **can** build them on my local dev machine using Visual Studio Enterprise or MSBuild commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue:

Since version 17.2 of the Buildtools for Visual Studio 2022 the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\AssemblyFolders.config` is missing.

This file contains the path to the assemblies, which could not have been found before (`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities`, ...).

My local installation of Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 **17.2** and installations of the Buildtools for Visual Studio 2022 **prior** 17.2 both install the file `AssemblyFolders.config` and thus have no issue.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution. I've been affected by the same issue. I've opened an [issue in the Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-Tools-2022:-warning-MSB3245:-Could/10093000), let's hope it gets fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install VSTO when you install Visual Studio. You will also want to avoid adding your target Office app (Excel in your case) as a reference from the COM tab unless Office is installed on your build server.